# jQuery AJAX URL change Phonegap

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cordova

How do I change the URL in Ajax and reload page with new content?

I make a service in WP:  `www.test.com/page/?u=test`

```
$_GET['u'];
```

and `while(..... new information)` works good.

But I have a problem with this..

```
$('#test').click(function(){
    uel = "http://......com/servisi302/?u=zanimljivosti";

        $('#page-content').hide(1000);
        $('#page-content').show(1000);
    alert(uel);

     return false;
     });

    jQuery.ajax({
        url : '' +uel,
        type : "POST",
        dataType : "json",
        data : "param=no",
        success : function(html){
            var QUERY = jQuery(".query");
            console.log(html);
            jQuery.each(html, function(key, value){
                console.log(value);
                QUERY.append("<div class='media well'><a href='#' class='pull-left'><img width='64' height='64' src='" + value.slika + "'class='media-object' alt='' /></a><div class='media-body'><h4 class='media-heading'><p>" + value.naslov + "</p></h4></div></div>");

            });
        }, error : function(e){
            alert(e);
        } 
    });
    });
```

How do I change the URL or variable and subsequently reload with the new content?

Comment: url:<?php echo $url ?>

Comment: i cannot use php beacuse  is mobile aplication phonegap include only html js , jq